# Matrix manipulation: Can I write this sum into one matrix operation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a setup as follows:

$$
v = \sum_{i=1}^{N} (y_i - Ax_i)^T \Sigma(y_i - Ax_i)
$$

Now y and x's are vectors and $(y-Ax_i)$ has dimensions $2 \times 1$. $\Sigma$ is a $2 \times 2$ diagonal matrix. So, the whole thing evaluates to a scalar and the sum over $N$ of these is also a scalar.

Is it possible to write this as one big vector-matrix-vector multiplication. I have been trying to get rid of this sum but have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain so I can improve the question.

Comment: If $A$ is a matrix, what is the product of $Ax_i$? It makes more sense if you do $(y-Ax)^T(y-Ax)$.

Comment: $x_i$ is itself a vector, so $Ax_i$ is well-defined and a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack the vectors $x_i$ and $y_i$:
$$
\tilde y:=\pmatrix{y_1\\ y_2\\ \vdots\\ y_N}, \ 
\tilde x:=\pmatrix{x_1\\ x_2\\ \vdots\\ x_N},
$$
and create block-diagonal matrices
$$
\tilde A = \pmatrix{ A & 0 & \dots \\0 & A & \dots \\ \vdots &\vdots & \ddots},
\tilde \Sigma = \pmatrix{ \Sigma & 0 & \dots \\0 & \Sigma & \dots \\ \vdots &\vdots & \ddots},
$$
then
$$
v = (\tilde y-\tilde A\tilde  x)^T\Sigma (\tilde y-\tilde A \tilde x).
$$

---

Another idea is to put the vectors one after another
$$
\hat y = \pmatrix{y_1 & y_2 & \dots & y_N},
\hat x = \pmatrix{x_1 & x_2 & \dots & x_N},
$$
then
$$
v = trace( (\hat y -A\hat x)^T \Sigma (\hat y-A\hat x))
$$

Comment: Thank you. I will try and implement these methods.

Comment: I doubt that any of these two versions is more efficient than the original sum. Maybe the computation of $\hat y - A\hat x$ is more efficient then the sum. However, you do not need to form the final product, as only its diagonal elements are needed.

Comment: The problem is that it is part of another computation where I need too find some conditional distribution which is a Gaussian and there is a lot of tedious algebra and it is much easier if I could manipulate these products as one expression.